# Makefile variable expansion not working as expected

Tags: makefile

I want to auto-create makefile rules based on a variable list (in my use case a set of files which I want to selectively build). However I have issues expanding the names.

I have created the following Makefile as an example (M(not)WE):

```
FILES_A=a1 a2 a3
FILES_B=b1 b2 b3
TARGET_BASES=A B

define test
  FILES := $(value FILES_$1)
  build_$1: $(addsuffix .ext, $(FILES))
  build_dummy_$1: $(FILES)
endef

$(foreach target, $(TARGET_BASES), $(eval $(call test,$(target))))
```

Running `make -p|grep build` I would expect the following output:

```
[...]
build_A: a1.ext a2.ext a3.ext
build_dummy_A: a1 a2 a3
build_B: b1.ext b2.ext b3.ext
build_dummy_B: b1 b2 b3
```

but instead I get

```
build_A:
build_dummy_A:
build_B: a1.ext a2.ext a3.ext
build_dummy_B: a1 a2 a3
```

and I do not know why. Can somebody shed some light on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understanding expansion around eval and call can be confusing.  That's why they're considered advanced items which should only be used if none of the simpler to understand facilities will solve the problem.

The issue here is that your macro `test` is evaluated first by the `call` function, before being passed to the `eval` function.  During that evaluation, the variable `FILES` is not not set yet and so it resolves to whatever it was set to the last time the eval ran: the first time it evaluates to empty and the second time it evaluates to the result after the first run, etc.

Basically the rule is that any variable you want to be expanded by `call` should have only one `$`, and any variable you want to be expanded by the `eval` needs to be escaped with `$$`.  So:

```
define test
  FILES := $$(value FILES_$1)
  build_$1: $$(addsuffix .ext, $$(FILES))
  build_dummy_$1: $$(FILES)
endef
```